# PHP - check variable is neither empty nor a string

Tags: php

I'm writing the php code which linked with database.

If I put the value on the php code for example

$pid = somevalue.

this some value will pass it to the next php file.

and I want to check this somevalue is not empty or not a string value

```
if( some condition ){

printf("Invalid input: %s\n", mysqli_connect_error());
echo "<br/><a href='index.php'>Back to previous page</a>";
exit();
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use

```
if (!empty($pid) && is_numeric($pid)) {
    // proceed
} else {
    // error
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$pid  = (int) $pid;
if ($pid) {
} else {
}
```

Comment: What will this do if `$pid` is 0?

Answer (score 0):

```
if(!empty($pid) and !is_string($foo)){
   printf("Invalid input: %s\n", mysqli_connect_error());
   echo "<br/><a href='index.php'>Back to previous page</a>";
   exit();
}
```

Comment: `empty` will also be true if a variable contains `0`.

Answer (score 0):

Just define it *as spoken*

```
if ( ! empty($foo) && ! is_string($foo) ) {

}
```